# react-spring: Can I really only set height by viewport heights (via `pages` attribute)?

Tags: reactjs, parallax, react-spring

I'm attempting to use `react-spring` to create a parallax effect on my site. I want the parallax container to be the background of the entire site, *plus* a 100vh "footer" at the bottom. Here's a simple diagram of what I mean:
[image: ideal react-spring page layout]

My issue is, according to the [react-spring parallax docs](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/props/parallax), the Parallax container requires a `pages` attribute, which "Determines the total space of the inner content where each page takes 100% of the visible container".

From my understand of this, as well as my testing, this means that I *have* to explicitly set the entire height of that Parallax Container based on divisions of 100% viewport height. This means I can't just have the Parallax Container contain the content of my site, which doesn't have a preset height, let alone height divided by 100vh.

So my question is, **can I have the Parallax Container of `react-spring` contain exactly my entire site's content, plus a 100vh at the bottom?**

Here's a sandbox demo of my problem, with the Parallax `pages` attribute set on line 29: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-spring-pageheight-question-c12er

Comment: Agreed. I'm converting a sticky nav page into full parallax and it seems not possible, and not a good idea, to break my layout into a stack of 100% viewport chunks... when the viewport might be too small in some cases.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone found a solution or explanation on how to use this properly?